# Isomorphisms between topological vector spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, gn.general-topology

Let $f : X \to Y$ be a continuous map of [complete](http://nlab.mathforge.org/nlab/show/complete+space) topological vector spaces. Suppose that $A \subseteq X$ and $B \subseteq Y$ are proper, dense linear subspaces, and that the restriction map $f : A \to B$ is an isomorphism. Is the original map an isomorphism?

Comment: Let $f$ be the inclusion of a dense subspace and let $A = B = X$...?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, I am a bit slow and do not understand your comment... Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @András: Suppose $Y$ is a topological vector space and $X$ a dense subspace of it. Let $f : X \to Y$ denote the inclusion. $f$ restricts to an isomorphism $f : A \to B$ where $A = B = X$, but $f$ is not itself an isomorphism if $X$ is not all of $Y$. But the question mark in my comment is because I assume Tom forgot a condition or something.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, thanks much for the obvious counterexample. You're right: I must be missing some condition.

Comment: Voting to close since this question needs further thought before continuing

Comment: Ok, I somehow implicitly assumed that you want to generalize the fact that for Banach spaces a densely defined isometry with dense range can be extended. But there you also need conditions.

Comment: NB when you ask for $f$ to be an isomorphism from A to B, you do mean a linear homeomorphism and not just a continuos linear bijection, right?

Comment: @YemonChoi, yes, linear homeomorphism. This question popped off of something else that I'm working on and obviously I didn't preserve all the conditions. I've edited it to rule out Qiaochu's counterexample.

Also: I had tried to close my question directly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Robertson & Robertson: [Topological Vector Spaces](http://books.google.hu/books?id=mV44AAAAIAAJ). Chapter VI (Completeness), Proposition 6 and Corollary 1.

If $E$ and $F$ are separated l.c. spaces, $t:E\to F$ continuous, linear, then there is a unique continuous linear extension $\hat t: \hat E \to \hat F$. Here $\hat E$ is the completition.

If further $t$ is an isimorphism onto $t(E)$, then $\hat t$ is an isomorphism of $\hat E$ onto $\hat t(\hat E)$.

Comment: Please. This is too basic to belong here.

Comment: You mean $t$, not $f$.

Comment: @ToddTrimble: Though this is indeed too basic for the expert, it does not belong to the standard mathematical curriculum, this is why I decided to answer.

Comment: @AndrásBátkai, thank you very much. Does "separated l.c." just mean "locally convex Hausdorff"?

Comment: @AndrasBatkai: I suppose we can agree to disagree about what is "standard".

Comment: @ András Bátkai: "If further $t$ is an isimorphism onto $t(E)$, then $\hat t$ is an isomorphism of $\hat E$ onto $\hat t(\hat E)$." This is false: Take any infinite-dimensional Banach space $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ and a discontinuouos linear form $u$ on it. Equip $X$ with the norm $x\mapsto\|\,x\,\|+|\,u(x)\,|\,$, and let $Y$ be the completion of $X$ when equipped with this norm. Then the identity $X\to X$ extends uniquely to a continuous linear map $Y\to X$ and is not an isomorphism.

Comment: @TaQ: I have to confess that I do not understand. Do you mean that on $X$ you take the old norm and on $Y$ the new one? But then the identity is not continuous...

Comment: @ András Bátkai. I put it in more detail: Let $E_0=(X,\nu_0)$ be the original Banach space with $\nu_0(x)=\|\,x\,\|$, and let $E_1=(X,\nu_1)$ be the incomplete normed space with $\nu_1(x)=\|\,x\,\|+|\,u(x)\,|$. Let $E=(Y,\nu)$ be the completion of $E_1$. Then the (continuous) identity $E_1\to E_0$ has a unique continuous noninjective extension $E\to E_0$. I add that in the present form the original question is completely trivial if "isomorphism" is to be interpereted as "linear homeomorphism". So MO is not the right place to pose such a question.

Comment: @TaQ: The question was about whether this trivial result has an extension to topological vector spaces. I cited the most general result I know in this context, the question is closed, I do not see the point of any further discussion here.